# How to fix ERROR ITMS-90680 StickerPackExtension.appex is not contained in a correctly named directory. It should be under "PlugIns"

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, ios-stickers, itunesconnect-analytics

Using **XCode 10.2.1**

Submitting my first stickers app for iOS for testing.

When uploading archive to itunesconnect I'm now getting this error:

> ERROR ITMS-90680: "Invalid directory. The bundle Payload/App
>   Name.app/App Name StickerPackExtension.appex is not contained in a
>   correctly named directory. It should be under "PlugIns".

My project structure is now:

```
App Name
 - Stickers.xcstickers
 - Products
   - App Name.app
   - App Name StickerPackExtension.appex
```

I don't see any way to move *.appex* to a **PlugIns** folder (non existing) as the error suggests.

Additionally the project structure is the **default structure** I'm getting when creating *"Sticker Pack App"* in Xcode.

So I'm not sure why is the process complaining about the .appex being in a wrong directory and I have no idea how to fix this to proceed further.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 8):

for me the problem was that extension was included in **Copy Bundle Resources** build phase. Make sure it's not there, it should be only under **Dependencies** and **Embed App Extension** build phases

Comment: This solved it fo me. In addition to the "Invalid directory" error, there was also a "CFBundleIdentifier collision" error, presumably just because the incorrectly copied bundle was then a duplicate of the embedded extension bundle.

Comment: It solved it for me! i found OneSignal extension in the Copy Bundle Resources build phase. thank you very much.